# Angular2 - Observable to know when complete

Tags: angular

I have a function that I call to submit an item.
When this action finishes I would like to display a modal to inform the user.

When the submit is clicked the following happens:

```
  this.itemsService.submitItem(submitItem);
```

Which in turns calls this method in the service.

```
submitItem(item: Item) {
    this.af.database.list('items').push(item);
}
```

I would like the submitItem method in the service to return an observable and be able to do something like .onComplete with the first function, like a callback.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried with flatmap? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

Comment: The item being `push`ed onto the list, is that a local (in memory list) or on some remote server? And either way, what does the `push` function return?

Comment: We need to know if `submitItem` returns either a promise or observable.

Comment: the subscribe method has three params success, error, completed